# unitTest karma-jasmine error

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Hi guys i have this error when lunch start karma karma.conf.js

> 20%20%20%20at%20Object.createInjector%20%5Bas%20injector%5D%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2FWebContent%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3Fbede50a38baeba3db7a4df46069
>   5d01ecb437273%3A4272%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.workFn%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2FWebContent%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular1.4.3%2Fangular-mocks.js%3F8bc8772418adb9b2fa9517
>   2525c3540d23e140f4%3A2393%3A52)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20attemptSync%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FZack%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3
>   91e45351df9ee35392d2e5cb623221a969fc009%3A1886%3A24)
>               at WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular.js:68:12
>               at forEach (WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular.js:336:20)
>               at loadModules (WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular.js:4346:5)
>               at Object.createInjector [as injector] (WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular.js:4272:11)
>               at Object.workFn (WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular-mocks.js:2393:52)
>               at WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular.js:4385:15
>   Chrome 51.0.2704 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 4 of 4 (1 FAILED) (0.117 secs / 0.074 secs)

My karma.conf.js is:

```
module.exports = function(config) {


config.set({
    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    'WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular.js',
    'WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular-*.js',
    'WebContent/assets/js/**/*.js',
    'WebContent/apps/gapsweb/**/*.js',
    'WebContent/apps/gapsweb/gaps.bootstrap.js',
    'WebContent/apps/gapsweb/components/**/*.test.js'
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
    'WebContent/assets/js/translation/*.js'
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: true,

// Concurrency level
// how many browser should be started simultaneous
concurrency: Infinity  })};
```

So what is the problem?? Where i wrong ??
Thanks guys for hel me!!

Comment: Please add jasmine code

Comment: describe("A suite", function() {
        it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });

Comment: it is only script?

Comment: Yes only this script for test karma-jasmine

Comment: remote this `'WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular-*.js',`

Comment: I removed it, but output the same error

Comment: check the `files`, file getting added mulitple times.

Comment: example, WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular-mocks.js',
WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular-routes.js' etc etc??

Comment: At the third line `**/*.js'` it will cause above two js added again

Answer (score 0):

So with the simple jasmine test work with this:

```
    'WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular.js',
    'WebContent/assets/js/jquery1.11.3/jquery.js',
    'WebContent/apps/gapsweb/**/*.js',
    'WebContent/apps/gapsweb/gaps.bootstrap.js',
    'WebContent/apps/gapsweb/components/**/*.test.js'
```

But when i  write this jasmine test (it's an custom directive) :

```
describe('Test Menu Directive', function () {
    var element, scope;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('CommonBusInfo');

        inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            element = angular.element('<jeep-menu application="{{codAppDirective}}"/>');
            $compile(element)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
        })
    });
    it('proviamo ', function () {
        console.log(111111);
        var x = element.find('application');
        x.triggerHandler('application');
        scope.$digest();
    });

});
```

This get this error:

> ```
>        at WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular.js:68:12
>         at forEach (WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular.js:336:20)
>         at loadModules (WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular.js:4346:5)
>         at Object.createInjector [as injector] (WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular.js:4272:11)
>         at Object.workFn (WebContent/assets/js/angular1.4.3/angular-mocks.js:2393:52)
> ```
>
> %20%20%20%20at%20Object.createInjector%20%5Bas%20injector%5D%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2FWebContent%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular1.4.3%2Fangular.js%3Fbede50a38baeba3db7a4df46069
>   5d01ecb437273%3A4272%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.workFn%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2FWebContent%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular1.4.3%2Fangular-mocks.js%3F8bc8772418adb9b2fa9517
>   2525c3540d23e140f4%3A2393%3A52)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20attemptSync%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FZack%2Fnode_modules%2Fjasmine-core%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3F3
>   91e45351df9ee35392d2e5cb623221a969fc009%3A1886%3A24)
>   Chrome 51.0.2704 (Windows 10 0.0.0) Test Menu Directive proviamo  FAILED
>           ReferenceError: module is not defined
>               at Object. (WebContent/apps/gapsweb/components/commons/menu/menu.directive.test.js:11:13)
>           TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
>               at Object. (WebContent/apps/gapsweb/components/commons/menu/menu.directive.test.js:22:28)
>   LOG: 6969
>   Chrome 51.0.2704 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.014 secs / 0.007 secs)

The directive is:

```
angular.module("CommonBusInfo", [])
.directive("jeepMenu", ['Restangular', function(Restangular){
    // Runs during compile
    console.log("gapsMenuDirective");
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var _urlTemplate = '',_codApp = attrs.application;

            if(angular.equals(_codApp,'gaps') || angular.equals(_codApp,'lirico') || angular.equals(_codApp,'topolino')){
                var utente = scope.userLogged;
                Restangular.one('users', utente.codUtente).one('readers', 'menu').one("commands", "menu")
                    .get()
                    .then(function (data) {
                        scope.loadingPercentage += 20;
                        scope.staticMenuTest = data.bodyResponse.dataWorkFlow.innerMenu;
                        _urlTemplate = 'components/commons/menu/menuDynamicView.html';
                    },function(err){
                        scope.loadingError = true;
                    });
                scope.staticMenuTest = [];
            }
            else{
                scope.loadingPercentage += 20;
                scope.staticMenuTest = '';
            }

            scope.getContentUrl = function(){
                return _urlTemplate;
            }
        },
        template: '<div ng-include="getContentUrl()"></div>'
    };
}])
```

Comment: So the problem is how inject the Restangular Service